# Wait for mongoose connection before continue

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a project in Node.js which is an API that connects to ChatGPT, Google and other API's, fetch, save, and send data.

So i've created a class for each API, a class for ChatGPT, a class for GoogleAPI and a class for MongoDb. But i've encountered a problem which I cannot overcome.

There is an API class which initialize all of them and I use it as a bridge between the different classes.

In the `constructor` class of the bridge:

```
var gptInstance = new ChatGPTManager();
var cronInstance = new CronJobManager();
var dbInstance = new DbManager();
var nlpInstance = new NaturalLanguage();
var apInstance = new AndroidPublisher(database);
```

The problem is that the DbManager is connecting to mongoose which takes a few seconds and I need to use the instance in the AndroidPublisher class.

For some reason I cannot figure the way to return the class and send it back to AndroidPublisher for it to use.

```
class API {
  constructor() {
    this.connect();
  }

  async connect() {
    //  API is connected.
    console.log(`\x1b[33m%s\x1b[0m`, '-> API Initialized.');
    var gptInstance = new ChatGPTManager();
    var cronInstance = new CronJobManager();
    var dbInstance = new DbManager();
    var nlpInstance = new NaturalLanguage();
    var apInstance = new AndroidPublisher();

    auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
      keyFile: config.GOOGLE_AUTH_KEY_FILE,
      scopes: config.GOOGLE_AUTH_SCOPES
    });

    authClient = await auth.getClient();

    nlpInstance.connect(authClient);
    apInstance.connect(authClient, dbInstance); <-- 'dbInstance' here is undefined
  }
}
```

I even tried setting a callback on the mongoose connect in the DbManager class and when I have the result, calling connect on both nlpInstance and apInstance, but still i'm getting undefined from database.

Comment: Is it actually a problem that the connection isn't active yet? Mongoose has [operation buffering](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#buffering).

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of [Connection Events](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#connection-events).

In your **DbManager** class, AFTER the instantiation of the connection with `mongoose.connect(...)`, you can access the *default connection* object with `mongoose.connection`, and listen for any type of event. Specifically, you'll need the `open` event (read the *Connection Events* paragraph of the Mongoose documentation linked above). Then, you just need to call `once` method on the *default connection* object and specify the event and the function to execute when that event happens.

Here is a full code sample, including the creation of the DB connection:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const dbConnectionString = '<Your MongoDB connection string here>';
mongoose.connect
(
    dbConnectionString,
    {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    }
);

const db = mongoose.connection;
db.once("open", () =>
{
    console.log("The connection was successful");

    // Put your class return logic here
});
```

With this, you can return your **DbManager** class only when the `open` event occurs.

Comment: Yes, I'm already doing that, but the 'open' event occurs in the DbManager class and I need it one level up on the API class. How would you suggest me doing that?

Comment: I can't comment on your question, so I'll write here. Maybe here Promises can be helpful. But we can't tell without seeing the actual code of your **DbManager**. Also, I think you intended to use `dbInstance = new DbManager();` instead of `dbInstance = new DB();`. So, if you can provide it, we could help more effectively